# ng-model values are always undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learn angular and have the most simple app, just a calculator that sends 2 values to a back end API for addition.

I have ng-model directives on 2 text fields with a default value of 'Enter Value' and initially this value is present in the form field.

However when I try to get the values I enter into the form fields they are always undefined, with a single variable or with the variables in an object.

I dont really understand why this is happening and any variables not ng-model bound to a field are not undefined:

```
 var calculatorApp = angular.module('calculatorApp', [
'config',
'ngRoute',  
'calculatorControllers', 
'calculatorServices'
]);

calculatorApp.config(['$routeProvider',
 function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.
     when('/calculator', {
       templateUrl: 'partials/calculator.html',
       controller: 'CalculatorCtrl'
     }).
     when('/about', {
       templateUrl: 'partials/about.html',
       controller: 'AboutCtrl'
     }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/calculator'
  });
 }]);

 calculatorControllers.controller('CalculatorCtrl', ['$scope', 'CalculatorService',
 function($scope, CalculatorService) {
$scope.orderProp = 'asc';
$scope.result = ' awaiting calculation';

$scope.sum = {
    val1: 'Enter Value',
    val2: 'Enter Value'
}   

$scope.add = function(val1, val2) {                 
    alert($scope.sum.val1); //always undefined even if form field shows value and so are val1 and val2 passed to this function from html page
    var promise = CalculatorService.add(val1, val2);

    promise.then(function successCallback(response) {               
        $scope.sum = response.data.result;      
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log('Error: ', response);           
    });             
};   
}]);


 <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">      

</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <label>
        Value One: <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="sum.val1" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="5" />
    </label>
    <label>
        Value Two: <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="sum.val2" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="5" />
    </label>
    <button ng-click="add(sum.val1, sum.val2)">Add</button>
    <div name="result" id="result">The result is <span ng-bind="result"></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Your DOM doesn't know about your controller.

I think you just forget to add `ng-controller="CalculatorCtrl"` on the parent `div`.

Or maybe it's just not written in your question ?

Comment: Sorry I was using templates and that is just the template piece of html. I will add the app.js to it. It is sort of working because the sum value and the defaulty values so get placed into the form fields when the page loads.

Comment: If I delete the ng-model directives from the form fields then the values are no longer undefined, so I dont know why but it is linked to ng-model.

Comment: You're saying that when inputs are not linked to the model with `ng-model`, it's working ?

Comment: And can you show us where the `ng-controller` directive is ?

Comment: Hi yes I added that to the code snippets above earlier: when('/calculator', {
       templateUrl: 'partials/calculator.html',
       controller: 'CalculatorCtrl'
     }).